# Error en envió de Correos con JAVA

Tags: java

Mi duda es que hace días que probaba el programa enviaba los correos sin problemas, pero ahora me aparece el siguiente error:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
>     nested exception is:
>       java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host

acá les dejo un poco de mi código, cualquier ayuda seria grandioso.
[image: Codigo del SendMail]

Comment: Hola O.Reglado, bienvenid@. Te recomiendo que sustituyas la imagen por el codigo en formato texto . Un saludo

Comment: Con puerto 465 te sale el mismo error?

Answer (score 1):

el problema se resolvió al ingresar a la cuenta.
Ya que marcaba como si se estuviera haciendo spam por la cantidad de correos
Gracias a todos por sus respuestas

Comment: saludos y bienvenido al sitio, te recomiendo que respondas esta pregunta mediante el click verde que aparece al costado de la respuesta que has redactado :D Por otro lado, dale click a http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y disfruta el recorrido por el sitio :D

Answer (score 0):

buenas amigo usa estas configuraciónse usa para gmail

```
     Properties props = new Properties();
                            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", user);
                            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

en el comando de user debes declarar un string con el correo que enviara los email